# Why does a Falcon Heavy cost more with a heavier payload?

Tags: launch, spacex, rockets, cost, falcon-heavy

While trying to find the priceof a Falcon Heavy launch, [I noticed the following](http://spaceflight101.com/spacerockets/falcon-heavy/):

> \$90M (<8.0mT), [\$130M (>8.0mT)]

Why is there a $40 million difference in price for the heavier payload? Also, that value seems suspect. Is this even a real price difference?

Comment: That might be the threshold above which they can't land the boosters and/or core so they have to fly in expendable mode.

Comment: @Hobbes Possibly, but as of right now, I didn't think that mattered... Besides, Falcon 9 can lift more than that payload, surely Falcon Heavy can do it without the extra cost...

Comment: On the SpaceX site, pricing for the F9 is quoted with a similar limit, $62M for up to 5.5 tons to GTO.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you might be right. The price is listed for a lower tonnage, one can presume the full cost launch is if the booster is considered expendable. Hmmm...

Comment: Repeat after me: price is not the same as cost.

Comment: Why wouldn't expendable/recoverable matter?

Comment: @RussellBorogove: due to current successful recovery rate being so low.

Comment: I wouldn't call the recovery rate low at this point, but even if you do, the only way they're going to improve the recovery rate is through practice. The value to SpaceX  of even an unsuccessful recovery attempt is enormous at this point in their long term plan.

Comment: @SF. I agree with RB. There's a value associated with *the chance of* of recovery, and if they don't want to change their prices all the time, they have to include the ramp in frequency plus the ramp in chance. There's also the value associated with less quantifiable like appearance, and finally there's the value associated with incremental learning - one learned fact may buy you *at least* one more recovery later on. Also there is (engine) capacity ramping which sometimes has awkward price points when demand is not so predictable.

Comment: In the original question where you ask "Is this even a real price difference?" I think you may be on the right track. Am I right that no Falcon 9 launch has delivered >8mT yet (I don't follow these things)? Notwithstanding your plausible answer that its re-usability, It wouldn't surprise me if the higher price band is more of a place-holder that will give way to a different pricing structure as a market takes shape.

Comment: @Puffin You are right to GTO, it, however, has delivered more to LEO. I'm pretty sure every Dragon mission weights more than that, the most I can find to GTO is about 4 mT.

Comment: I was going on the summary box in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_%28spacecraft%29  which gives dry mass 4.2T plus payload 3.3T to ISS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is in the re-usability factor. The number on the [Falcon 9 cost](http://www.spacex.com/about/capabilities) page is as follows:

- Falcon 9 to GTO- 5.5 t to GTO \$62m
- Falcon Heavy to GTO- 8 t to GTO \$90m

However, it lists the capacities as follows:

- Falcon 9- 8.3 t
- Falcon Heavy- 22 t

One can only assume that the reduction in price is for a mission that allows for landing the booster again, to try for re-usability. The full capacity, that doesn't allow for landing, costs more. There might even be a likelihood of return computed, a booster that needs to carry more weight has a higher chance of being damaged.

Comment: It is a possible reason.I am wondering for something,it means that Falcon H will be fully reusable(side boosters and the core)if the payload won't  be more than 8 t to GTO. For heavier payloads the core probably won't be reusable,this rises the price.But I won't be so sure for this.If Falcon 9 booster could be reusable with 5.5 t to GTO,in my opinion Falcon H with the capacity that it has(more than double of Falcon 9)could be reusable even with a payload at least 10 t and even more.

Comment: I would say that even the level of refurbishments could be a reason, more damage to the core because of high velocities and less fuel remaining at the tanks so can't burn longer to decent slower all the time. So the booster will have a higher level of damage and needs more refurbishment, so more costs.

Comment: @MarkBoghdani Honestly, the Falcon Heavy price difference from the Falcon 9 is so little that I am not really surprised. I suspect that the scale goes up somewhat gradually, there is likely a 2 booster of 3 recovery price, as well as a completely expended price.

Comment: SpaceX uses the metric unit kg (kilogramm) but you use the wrong unit millitonne. What about using Mg (Megagramm)?

Comment: mt= metric ton. mT is a using used, but might not be the best choice. Will just use t, which is the best choice.